# How to query a document while populating it's field with a document from another collection in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have three schemas, call them A, B and C.

All schemas have the auto generated `_id`, `name`, and `active` fields. But C has an extra field `relations`, which is an object with two fields in it `a_id`, and `b_id`. Something like that:

```
{
  _id,
  name,
  active,
  relations: {
    a_id,
    b_id
  }
}
```

What I would like to query all documents from C, where the related A, and B documents both active. So replace the ids: `a_id`, and `b_id` with the actual corresponding documents.

Something like: `C.findMany({ 'relations.a_id': true, 'relations.b_id': true })`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try aggregation query,

- `$lookup` with A collection, pass `a_id` in let, under the pipeline check `$match` condition for `a_id` and active status `true`
- `$lookup` with B collection, pass `b_id` in let, under the pipeline check `$match` condition for `b_id` and active status `true`
- `$project` to show required fields, `$arrayElemAt` to get first element from returned result from lookup, check if it null using `$ifNull` then it will return same id

```
C.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "A",
      let: { id: "$relations.a_id" },
      pipeline: [{
          $match: {
            active: true,
            $expr: { $eq: ["$$id", "$_id"] }
          }
      }],
      as: "relations.a_data"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "B",
      let: { id: "$relations.b_id" },
      pipeline: [{
          $match: {
            active: true,
            $expr: { $eq: ["$$id", "$_id"] }
          }
      }],
      as: "relations.b_data"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      active: 1,
      relations: {
        a_id: {
          $ifNull: [
            { $arrayElemAt: ["$relations.a_data", 0] },
            "$relations.a_id"
          ]
        },
        b_id: {
          $ifNull: [
            { $arrayElemAt: ["$relations.b_data", 0] },
            "$relations.b_id"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fqpTMUydgw5)

Comment: If I run the playground (much appreciated, thanks), it returns just the id for B. Is it the same for you as well? If not, why is that?

Comment: the active status is false of `b_id: 2` record in B collection.